# Referencing another page programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

*Note: For the purposes of this question, I am using the "Asp.Net Webpage with Master Page" template built in MS Visual Studio 2013.*

My master page contains a label that specifies any exception errors. It must be defined in the master page for positioning reasons.

The default web page (Default.aspx.cs) gets the error message from a class, which is defined in the page.

My handler class file produces the error message like so:

```
public string errorString...  

...catch (Exception e)
{
    errorString = e.Message.ToString();
}
```

Then Default.aspx.cs instantiates the handler and string like so:

```
 Program.invoiceHandler handler = new invoiceHandler();
 string errorString 
     {get; set;}
```

and from within one of its classes populates the string:

```
errorString = handler.errorString;
```

So, ideally, Site.Master.cs should be able to populate the error string by looking at the default web page:

```
errorLabel.Text = _Default.errorString;
```

This does not work. Intellisense gives me three options when I type in `_Default`:

- `CreateHTMLTextWriterFromType`
- `Equals`
- `ReferenceEquals`

How do I access Default.aspx.cs from Site.Master.cs, and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Instead of accessing Default.aspx.cs from Site.Master.Cs, it could be more simple to set label's text directly from Default.aspx.cs. To access a label declared in the master page, you will need to create a Public Property on masterPage.

Comment: @Rumpel I'm not sure how to do that, could you provide an example? It's probably obvious, but I'm blind to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of what I was talking about. I have copied the code directly of one of my projects and it is not c#. It is vbnet, sorry for the inconvenience.

In Site.Master.cs add this code:

```
Public ReadOnly Property getErrorLabel() As [label_type]
    Get
        Return Me.[label]
    End Get
End Property
```

Then in Default.aspx.cs, after having set "errorString", you can use this code to set the text of the label in your MasterPage

```
Ctype(Master, [MasterType]).getErrorLabel().Text = errorString
```

Obviously you have to change [label_type], [label] and [MasterType] for the correct values.

An other solution is to use this piece of code in Default.aspx.cs (also in vbnet, sorry :D )

```
Page.Master.FindControl("label_id").Text = errorString
```

*This is the corresponding code (As best I can translate) in C#:*
Site.Master.cs:

```
public Label getErrorLabel
        {
            get { return this.errorLabel; }
        }
```

Default.aspx.cs:
`((SiteMaster)Master).getErrorLabel.Text = errorString;`

Comment: Looks sound so far, no errors. Hopefully this works come runtime! I added the translation, hope you don't mind

Comment: No problem ^^. I'm glad I could help